# Image position is changing on hover (only on Firefox)

Tags: css, html, firefox, position

I don't know the reason, but I am facing some problems on firefox.

[image]

The flag shoud not move on hover... but only on firefox the flag is changing the position.

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <code>
    <span>E</span>xample
  </code>
<div id="language">
  <a href="/en/home"><img alt="England" src="/assets/england-5be6776a259abf9711f460282fb6867b.png" /></a>
  <a href="/br/home"><img alt="Brazil" src="/assets/brazil-e70ce4232fd8b49307a857cb63f6625a.png" /></a>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #333333;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 2em;
}

header span {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

code {
float: left;
}

#language {
  float: right;
}

#language a img{
  height: 25px;
}
```

I have tried to add the below to my css without success.

```
#language a img:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

Firefox 18.0.2, Mac OS X V. 10.7.5

Thanks to @KatieK I managed to simulate the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/sqCuL/2/. I think something else in my css is causing the problem.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted that would cause that. This demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/sqCuL/ shows no movement when I hover the links.  Can you provide something which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Which Firefox version are you using (and which OS) ?

Comment: yeah, you must not be showing us some important stuff

Comment: Your website's link is broken

Comment: @KatieK I think something else in my css is causing the problem. I paste the full css and the problem appears now here: http://jsfiddle.net/sqCuL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine in latest version of Firefox as stated in the comments.
However you could consider using a CSS reset, be it as simple as:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or more exhaustive as [K. Meyer's one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (it is just [one of many exemples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485720/which-html5-reset-css-do-you-use-and-why)).

**EDIT after live demo link**:

The faulty CSS is:

```
nav li a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active, #current
{
    display: block;
}
```

Which change the way Firefox layout the images during mouse hovering. Not a clue why Firefox is the only one triggering this behaviour thought.

Seems that in Chrome the CSS selector is matched even without hovering with the mouse (probably because of `a:visited` or `a:active`) always displaying the two image as `block`.

Comment: the css reset is in the first line of my css

Comment: I changed the line to `nav li a, nav li a:hover, nav li a:visited, nav li a:active, #current {` and problem solved. Many thanks.