# Article tag remove padding

Tags: css, html

I want to use the article tag to create a stacked comments section underneath a forum post. I tried using

```
article
{
   padding:0px;
   margin: 0px;
 }
```

but there is still seperation between articles, is there a way to have them stacked on top of one another with no space?

### EDIT

```
   <article class="postComment">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-6 post-content">
                           <p>Sweet!.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer post-info-b">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2/18/2016 9:52:40 AM <i class="fa fa-user"> </i><a href="Resident?id=2bfc98cc-88b0-4977-8dbb-73912dfef461">steve.biermann</a>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </article>





           <article class="postComment">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-6 post-content">
                           <p>Thanks for the information!.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer post-info-b">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2/16/2016 12:30:44 PM <i class="fa fa-user"> </i><a href="Resident?id=712cd4ae-b5d0-49c9-ad3f-5168f2adc947">sam.cromer</a>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </article>




             </article>
```

CSS

```
              .postComment {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
                }
```

Comment: post some code example because there are a lot of possible reasong You still can see this padding.

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to find the culprit element.

Comment: [Article tags don't have built in padding or margins](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/hfcqgyk0/1/), so.....

Comment: it wouldnt matter if they did I removed them so its something else. Im using bootstrap im guessing its something in one of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Read anything about [reset CSS technic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485720/which-html5-reset-css-do-you-use-and-why)

There is a big probability that You have to padding / margin inherited from one of parents of your article.

Of course You can also use firebug / chrome dev tools to check where exactly is declaration responsible for property You want to reset.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit.. The panel class has a margin-bottom : 20px;