# How to display a list of <article> the same cross-browser?

Tags: html, cross-browser, article

Firefox and Opera seem to put articles after each other while Chrome gives a line break after each one. Which one is correct and how would you get them display the preferred style the same cross browser?

```
<html>
<body>

<article>
Item 1
</article>

<article>
Item 2
</article>

<article>
Item 3
</article>

<article>
Item 4
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

Opera 11.01
[image]

Chrome 9.0
[image]

Comment: They're being treated as `inline` elements in Opera, and as `block` elements in Chrome.

Comment: Question [#3277671](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277671/css-reset-for-html5) has some useful information for you.

Comment: @jnpcl, I believe the HTML4 spec says something about displaying unrecognized elements as inline and essentially ignoring them. Good browsers will allow you to specify styles for unrecognized elements, which is why you can set `display: block` and have the elements work the same (except for Internet Exploder, which just ignores the element all-together).

Comment: +1s all round, Thanks. @jnpcl You are correct in thinking I am new these standard and practices, very useful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set either `display: inline` or `display:block` in CSS.  (whichever one you want)